# Obtener la posible url en caché de una imagen precargada

Tags: javascript, imagen, url

Con este código, obtengo el ancho y alto de una imagen en una URL dada de un servidor remoto:

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
    return { ancho: img.width, alto: img.height };
};
img.src = urlFoto;
```

Entiendo que con 'img.onload' la imagen que hemos creado con 'new Image()' se carga en la caché u otra parte del entorno del navegador.

¿Habría forma de obtener la url de la imagen cargada en la caché (u otra parte) del navegador? (no la url de la imagen remota que se obtiene con img.src).